# Overwrite style for specific pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know if this is possible, but this is what I am trying to achieve. 
For class category icon and icon-location-pin-4 styles are generating automatically in code. Actually they are defined inside the plugin in wp. If I change color there, it reflects on all pages.

For some pages on the site, I don't want to have these colors displayed, I want specific colors just for few sites and those colors will remain always.

```
<span class="category-icon" style="background-color: #649744;">
   <i class="icon-location-pin-4" style="color: #ffffff; "></i>
</span>
```

I am not sure how to achieve this, or it is possible? On some pages, the code will look like.. This is what I want to achieve.

```
<span class="category-icon" style="background-color: #fff;">
   <i class="icon-location-pin-4" style="color: #000; "></i>
</span>
```

I am having two rows in same section, I want it to apply only for second row..

```
<div class="listing-details footer-section">
    <ul class="preview-category-list">
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <span class="category-icon" style="background-color: #281784;">
                    <i class="fa fa-ticket" style="color: #fff; "></i>
                </span>
                <span class="category-name">Category 1</span>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="listing-details footer-section">
    <ul class="preview-category-list">
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <span class="category-icon" style="background-color: #281784;">
                    <i class="icon-location-pin-4" style="color: #fff; "></i>
                </span>
                <span class="category-name">Category 2</span>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to make changes for for backgorund where icon-location-pin-4 is printed out, not for code above. But when I change backgorund, it gets applied for code above too

Comment: You can add a very specific CSS rule to your (child) theme's style.css: `body.page-id-15 .icon-location-pin-4 { color: #000 !important; }`

Comment: Each and every page has different body class in wp... For example about page means .body.page-template-about { }.. like that u can add the css for specific page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible? Nearly certainly.

You can make the CSS selector more specific to include/exclude whatever is required.
Without seeing the DOM of the pages involved, it is impossible to be exact, but if for instance you only wanted this on 1 page, select an element unique to that page that is a parent of the target element.

Re; the other raised question, targetting only the 2nd instance of something we can use nth-child() - although, it is far better to be able to generate the HTML ourselves, and attach a custom class we can target with CSS that way - but we can't always get what we want :).

Using the updated code from above, take some HTML that looks like this:

```
<!-- page #1 example -->

<div class="pretend-body-page-1"> <!-- pretend this is the body on page 1 -->
  <div class="listing-details footer-section">
      <ul class="preview-category-list">
          <li>
              <a href="">
                  <span class="category-icon" style="background-color: #281784;">
                      <i class="fa fa-ticket" style="color: #fff; ">fa fa-ticket placeholder / example text, due to not having font awesome in code pen - should be removed</i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="category-name">Category 1</span>
              </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-details footer-section">
      <ul class="preview-category-list">
          <li>
              <a href="">
                  <span class="category-icon" style="background-color: #281784;">
                      <i class="icon-location-pin-4" style="color: #fff; ">fa fa-ticket placeholder / example text, due to not having font awesome in code pen - should be removed</i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="category-name">Category 2</span>
              </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>
<span style="color: white;">fake page divide</span>
<hr/>

<!-- page #2 example -->

<div class="pretend-body-page-2"> <!-- pretend this is the body on page 2 -->
  <div class="listing-details footer-section">
      <ul class="preview-category-list">
          <li>
              <a href="">
                  <span class="category-icon" style="background-color: #281784;">
                      <i class="fa fa-ticket" style="color: #fff; ">fa fa-ticket placeholder / example text, due to not having font awesome in code pen - should be removed</i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="category-name">Category 1</span>
              </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-details footer-section">
      <ul class="preview-category-list">
          <li>
              <a href="">
                  <span class="category-icon" style="background-color: #281784;">
                      <i class="icon-location-pin-4" style="color: #fff; ">fa fa-ticket placeholder / example text, due to not having font awesome in code pen - should be removed</i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="category-name">Category 2</span>
              </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following CSS hopefully is selecting/achieving what you've requested:

```
// only target this element on the specific page
div.pretend-body-page-2 i.icon-location-pin-4:nth-child(1) {
    /**
      Unfortunately !important is required to override the 'inline style' used in the html
      <i style="{inline_style}"

      Ideally we would avoid inline style, as well as the use of !important, 
      as nothing can override !important.

      It is better to rely on the specificity of selectors to target elements
    */
    color: #00ae12 !important;
}
```

https://codepen.io/mikeyjk/pen/KKpMmpv

**Edit:**

> I need to modify cat-icon set it to white color, and icon-location-pin-check-2 to black color, in that case the only pin will be showing no green color around. But only changes for regions, where icon-location-pin-check-2 no on cat above.

I think you're asking for a few different things not in the original question.. but here's my best effort interpretation..:

CSS for modifying the background colour of .cat-icon:

```
.cat-icon { background-color: #ffffff !important; }
.cat-icon i { color: #000000 !important; }
```

CSS for modifying the color of .icon-location-pin-check-2 to black:

```
.buttons.button-1 { color: #000000; }
```

I think you might need to attach a screenshot demonstrating what changes you need if that is still not it, I'm finding it a bit confusing understanding the requirements.

**Double edit:**

Okay, thanks for the screenshot, I think this is what you are asking for:

```
.lf-item-container .listing-details:nth-child(3) .cat-icon {
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

In english, taking the parent of both of those rows, identifying which row we want to target (the 3rd under the parent .lf-item-container), then specifying the element we want to modify.

If you added another row to that container, this CSS would be an issue.
As mentioned in a perfect world we could change the HTML output to make the CSS a bit simpler.

Comment: It works but It gets applied on both rows. I have updated the question, it is tricky as I have two same rows. I want to apply it only for icon-location-pin-4. When tI change background-color for category-icon it gets applied for the element above.

Comment: The question has changed somewhat but I'll update my answer in a bit to reflect a CSS selector which can target based on the number it shows up, assuming it is always 2nd in actuality

Comment: Thanks for helping but it doesnt work,  body.page-id-27 .category-icon:nth-child(2)  { background-color: #fff !important; }  
body.page-id-27 .icon-location-pin-4:nth-child(2)  { color: #000 !important; }   it doesnt make any chages, when I set nth-child(1) It updates both rows

Comment: @Marko no worries, I'll do up a codepen example later. Have you ever used codepen? It might be useful for you to play with it there as well.

Comment: No I haven't, kinda beginner. I appreciate your helping

Comment: You're welcome, everyone starts somewhere, I'm not an expert/might be getting confused as well. Hopefuly the updated answer is a bit more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, still behaving same. If you take a look at https://www.staging2.cannabisstack.com/ -> all regions (countries) I need to modify (I need to remove the green background and color pin with #000) for some reasons it doesnt work

Comment: What do you need to modify? The "add a listing" button? `icon-location-pin-check-2`?

Comment: I need to modify cat-icon set it to white color, and icon-location-pin-check-2 to black color, in that case the only pin will be showing no green color around. But only changes for regions, where icon-location-pin-check-2 no on cat above.

Comment: I added screenshoot. I think you will understand, I need to modify only those with green color on that page.

Comment: Updated - tested using the staging2 site and it seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give styles for odd/event row then you can use :child() css selector like as below :

```
div.listing-details:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

The above code only usable when you want to apply CSS for 2nd div with 'listing-details' class.

If you want to apply css for all event div's  then you can use following code :

```
 div.listing-details:nth-child(even) {
      background: red;
    }
```

Or you want to apply css for all div's but particular page then you can use ID(#) for that, like as follow:

```
#ID_Of_Page div.listing-details:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```